# What's the most hardy red fleshed apple for the Pacific Northwest?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, plant-recommendations, apples

I had two wonderful red fleshed apples in Birch Bay, Washington.  We've moved to St. Helens, Oregon and I can't find any here.  I'd love to replace them.  Does anyone know where I might find these and which ones would be the most hardy for this area?

Answer (score 2):

St. Helens, Oregon is in USDA hardiness zone 8, and [Winter Red Flesh](http://tooleystrees.com/product/77/) crabapple will grow well up to zone 9, and will grow well in your area with irrigation. This is a very attractive small tree, with bronze leaves, and lots of pink/purple flowers in spring.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an actual apple rather than a crabapple, check out Pink Pearl (pink fleshed not red), good in low chill areas. Zone 8 isn't high chill, but its not exactly low chill either, so it might be worth trying Xmas Pearman or Grenadine, both with red flesh, though they do require cold winters.